Table column that supports an array of values and is filterable
Given a dataset such as:
[
    {
        "name": "Alice",
        "type": "student",
        "languages": [
            "English",
            "French"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "type": "student",
        "languages": [
            "English"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Carol",
        "type": "student",
        "languages": [
            "French",
            "German",
            "Spanish"
        ]
    }
]

I want to display the languages in a single column and also have a filter that can have multiple values checked.
This is close to this sample: Table Filter except each row in the column contains an array of values, not just one. Do p-tables and filters support this?
